# How to use volatile variable another function in embedded c

Tags: c, embedded

If (expression 1) runs that means gas leakage, it will run (expression2) and (expression 3). (Expressions 2) works only one time during the gas leakage. If gas sensor detects second time after returning sensor signal go down, it will have to run (expression 2). The problem is that code skips (expression 2) at the second time gas leakage.

I am going to do that (expression 2) runs one time during the gas leakage. It must work second time gas leakage.

```
void Sensor_buzzer (){

if (Check_Gas_Voltage(Sensor1)){        // expression 1

    static uint8_t i=0;

    if (i==0){                                           // expression 2

        _delay_ms(300);              

        Buzzer_Tune();

        Sensor_Relay_Mechanism();

        i++;

    }

    else if (i>0){                                   // expression 3

        Buzzer_Tune();

    } 

}
```

Comment: The first time `i=0`, then `i++;` and then `i` stays at `1` to the end of the universe. (there are no other expression that change the value of `i`). What would you expect to happen?

Comment: This is a simple logical bug unrelated to `volatile`. Think about `volatile` only when you have interrupts and/or hardware registers around.

Comment: @Eugene Sh How can I reach? Could you advice me?

Comment: The gas might be [volatile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(chemistry)), the variable is not [volatile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 0):

How about setting `i` to zero if there is no gas leak

```
void Sensor_buzzer ()
{
    static uint8_t i = 0;

    if (Check_Gas_Voltage(Sensor1))
    {

        if (i==0)
        {
            _delay_ms(300);              
            Buzzer_Tune();
            Sensor_Relay_Mechanism();
            i++;
        }
        else if (i > 0)
        {
            Buzzer_Tune();
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The else condition can also be removed since it’s never set negative.

Comment: @Arkku True: `else if (i > 0)` --> `else`.

Comment: You might also need to reverse the effects of `Sensor_Relay_Mechanism()`  in the final `else` where you reset the value of `i` so that the behaviour will be the same on subsequent detections.